# Where to put package vignettes for CRAN submission?

Tags: r, cran, package-development

From the [Writing R Extensions Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes), I read that

> As from R 2.14.0 the preferred location for the Sweave sources is the
>   subdirectory vignettes of the source packages, but for compatibility
>   with earlier versions of R, vignette sources will be looked for in
>   inst/doc if vignettes does not exist.

However, when I create a `vignettes` subdirectory of the package source, when I run `devtools::check()` or `R CMD check` I get a warning for `Package vignette(s) without corresponding PDF`. If I put the vignette (.Rnw and .pdf) in `inst/doc` the check completes without complaints. I tried looking in my library at installed packaged and did not see any directories named `vignettes`. Should I still use the deprecated location?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You put the `.Rnw` sources in `vignettes/` as you did, but you missed out a critical step; don't check the source tree. The expected workflow is to build the source tarball and then check that tarball. Building the tarball will create the vignette PDF.

```
R CMD build ../foo/pkg
R CMD check ./pkg-0.4.tar.gz
```

for example will build a source package tarball from the sources in `../foo/pkg` creating the `.tar.gz` package in the current directory with the package name and version appended. Then you run `R CMD check` on that source package.

If you want your vignette built for you put it in `vignettes/` and build the source package. At some future date, R Core may remove the ability to build vignettes from `inst/doc` so go with the advised location now and avoid check the sources directly.

Answer (score 13):

I had a hard time interpreting this too.

I believe the intention is that you should put the `.Rnw` file in `vignettes/` and the PDF (suitably compacted) in `inst/doc/`, which technically agrees with the documentation if you read carefully enough. (That is, it says the *sources* should go in `vignettes/`. I don't see where it says in so many words that you ought to put the corresponding PDF in `inst/doc/`, but it doesn't **not** say it, and that interpretation seems to make `R CMD check` happy ...)

The resolution is in @GavinSimpson's answer (i.e. one is expected to build the tarball and then check it, rather than checking the source directory itself). *(My two cents is that it might be  best if R-core officially deprecated (and eventually removed) direct source checking rather than confusing all of us groundlings ...)*

Comment: The intention is for you to not be checking the package sources but to check the *packaged* version, i.e. the source package as created by an `R CMD build` operation.

Comment: If you place `foo.Rnw` and `foo.pdf` in `vignettes/`, the pdf will automagically get transferred to installed `doc` directory. No need for manual intervention via `inst/doc`.

Comment: The something else is wrong as numerous packages, including some of mine I converted, work with `vignettes/`.

Comment: I think the resolution is in @GavinSimpson's answer (i.e. one is expected to build the tarball and then check it, rather than checking the source directory itself).  Question: if so, would it be a better idea for R-core to officially deprecate (and eventually remove) direct source checking rather than confusing all of us groundlings?